# How to convert a string to JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json, string, object

I have the following result from an SQL query:

```
{"Coords":[
    {"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},
    {"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},
    {"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27770755361785","Longitude":"-9.011979642121824","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:09 GMT+0100 (IST)"},
    {"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"},
    {"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"} 
    ]
}
```

It is currently a string in PHP.  I know it's already in JSON form, is there an easy way to convert this to a JSON object?

I need it to be an object so I can add an extra item/element/object like what "Coords" already is.

Comment: @user2363025 this is your string converted to valid JSON: http://pastebin.com/R16NVerw

Comment: @MiroMarkarian Although the JSON is valid, you broke the date format xD

Comment: The JsonLint did that I didn't. I posted just to show what is valid. When converting programatically, it won't happen

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Thanks, that's a good link to have!

Comment: I saw that you edited the question, tell me: the initial data are in JSON format you want to convert to PHP variables (Array/Object - stdClass), add data and convert to JSON again? Note: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

What @deceze said is correct, it seems that your JSON is malformed, try this:

```
{
    "Coords": [{
        "Accuracy": "30",
        "Latitude": "53.2778273",
        "Longitude": "-9.0121648",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jun 28 2013 11:43:57 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    }, {
        "Accuracy": "30",
        "Latitude": "53.2778273",
        "Longitude": "-9.0121648",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jun 28 2013 11:43:57 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    }, {
        "Accuracy": "30",
        "Latitude": "53.2778273",
        "Longitude": "-9.0121648",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jun 28 2013 11:43:57 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    }, {
        "Accuracy": "30",
        "Latitude": "53.2778339",
        "Longitude": "-9.0121466",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jun 28 2013 11:45:54 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    }, {
        "Accuracy": "30",
        "Latitude": "53.2778159",
        "Longitude": "-9.0121201",
        "Timestamp": "Fri Jun 28 2013 11:45:58 GMT+0100 (IST)"
    }]
}
```

Use `json_decode` to convert String into Object (`stdClass`) or array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

**[edited]**

I did not understand what do you mean by *"an official JSON object"*, but suppose you want to add content to json via PHP and then converts it right back to JSON?

assuming you have the following variable:

```
$data = '{"Coords":[{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27770755361785","Longitude":"-9.011979642121824","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:09 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"}]}';
```

You should convert it to *Object* (stdClass):

`$manage = json_decode($data);`

But working with `stdClass` is more complicated than PHP-Array, then try this (use second param with `true`):

`$manage = json_decode($data, true);`

This way you can use array functions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

**adding an item:**

```
$manage = json_decode($data, true);

echo 'Before: <br>';
print_r($manage);

$manage['Coords'][] = Array(
    'Accuracy' => '90'
    'Latitude' => '53.277720488429026'
    'Longitude' => '-9.012038778269686'
    'Timestamp' => 'Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)'
);

echo '<br>After: <br>';
print_r($manage);
```

**remove first item:**

```
$manage = json_decode($data, true);
echo 'Before: <br>';
print_r($manage);
array_shift($manage['Coords']);
echo '<br>After: <br>';
print_r($manage);
```

any chance you want to save to json to a *database* or a *file*:

```
$data = '{"Coords":[{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.277720488429026","Longitude":"-9.012038778269686","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27770755361785","Longitude":"-9.011979642121824","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:09 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"},{"Accuracy":"65","Latitude":"53.27769091555766","Longitude":"-9.012051410095722","Timestamp":"Fri Jul 05 2013 12:02:17 GMT+0100 (IST)"}]}';

$manage = json_decode($data, true);

$manage['Coords'][] = Array(
    'Accuracy' => '90'
    'Latitude' => '53.277720488429026'
    'Longitude' => '-9.012038778269686'
    'Timestamp' => 'Fri Jul 05 2013 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (IST)'
);

if (($id = fopen('datafile.txt', 'wb'))) {
    fwrite($id, json_encode($manage));
    fclose($id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you been pulling out my hair as to why the array I am pushing to another array is being shown as a string instead of an object.

Comment: If you're not dealing with `stdClass` and it's not working with the simple `json_decode` function, by casting the string as an `(array)` beforehand did the trick for me.

Comment: for my case adding the true flag solved it. I was just passing the data without the true parameter but I wasn't getting the correct response. Thank you.

Answer (score 30):

To convert a valid JSON string back, you can use the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) method.

To convert it back to an object use this method:

```
$jObj = json_decode($jsonString);
```

And to convert it to a associative array, set the second parameter to `true`:

```
$jArr = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

By the way to convert your mentioned string back to either of those, you should have a valid JSON string. To achieve it, you should do the following:

1. In the `Coords` array, remove the two `"` (double quote marks) from the start and end of the object.
2. The objects in an array are comma seprated (`,`), so add commas between the objects in the `Coords` array..

And you will have a valid JSON String..

Here is your JSON String I converted to a valid one: http://pastebin.com/R16NVerw

Comment: Yes! Instead of typecasting into an array, we can use the _assoc_ parameter of `json_encode`. Quoting the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php): "When `TRUE`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays."

Answer (score 10):

you can use this for example

```
$array = json_decode($string,true)
```

but validate the Json before. You can validate from http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 7):

If you don't pass second parameter, or pass false, json_decode() will parse JSON to stdClass object therefore you can use "->" arrow notation to access the object properties.

```
<?php

// Store JSON data in a PHP variable
$json = '{"email":"john@doe.com"}';

$obj = json_decode($json, false);
print $obj->email;

?>
```

### Output

```
john@doe.com
```

Answer (score 0):

@Miro Markaravanes save me tons of time of this.
In my case I stored the string of a JSON object similar to OP's in my database. When calling it back it had double quotes at the beginning and end of the string.

Due to this every time I tried to using `json_decode` it wouldn't work.

So I did the following:

```
    $data = substr($data, 1);
    $data = substr($data, 0, -1);
    $data = json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with `json_encode()`.

And look again [Valid JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)