# Convert string with array of json (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I stored array of JSON in mysql as a string

```
[{"id": 1, "mark": 5}, {"id": 2, "mark": 3}, {"id": 3, "mark": 2}]
```

When I try to use it

```
@foreach ($places as $place)
   @foreach ($place->rates as $rate)

      {{var_dump($rate->marks)}}

   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

There is a problem. 
*$rate->marks* is a string. How shoul I decode it to array?

**UPD**

of course I tried to use json_decode, but it returns error

`htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

**SOLVED**

I', stupid. Problem was not in json_decode. I tried to print result with {{ }} which needs string as argument.

Comment: First decode the json string and then use it in foreach loop.

Comment: use `json_decode($rate->marks);`

Comment: @splash58 of course I tried to use json_decode, but it returns error

htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string to JSON object php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488207/convert-a-string-to-json-object-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `rate` in your json, and also no `marks`.

[Check Online](https://3v4l.org/k7kTG)

```
$json = '[{"id": 1, "mark": 5}, {"id": 2, "mark": 3}, {"id": 3, "mark": 2}]';
$places = json_decode ($json);

foreach ($places as $place)
      var_dump($place->mark);
```

Design the code for the Laravel, Online Debug does't have that feature.

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `json_decode` your marks and then iterate them as array. Something like this (I don't know if it works in Laravel but you can get an idea):

```
@foreach ($places as $place)
   @foreach ($place->rates as $rate)
      @foreach (json_decode($rate->marks) as $mark)
        {{var_dump($mark->mark)}}
      @endforeach
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = '[{"id": 1, "mark": 5}, {"id": 2, "mark": 3}, {"id": 3, "mark": 2}]';

$places = json_decode($str);

foreach ($places as $place) {
    echo 'id=>' . $place->id;
    echo 'mark=>' . $place->mark;
    echo "<br>";
}
```