# How to pass Array with values using Ajax in jquery and get the values in Php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax posted parameter as below:

```
$.ajax({
      url:'url',
      data:{ary:my_ary},
  ...
```

Where value in the `my_ary = Array([0]=> Test Text,[1]=> test Text2)`

Now i need to get values from this array using a **foreach() loop** like this:

```
 foreach($_POST['ary'] as $val){
         echo($val.'<br>');
   }
```

But it is showning the following error

> An invalid arguments passed to foreach loop

Comment: just do print_r($_POST); and show the output from the php file

Comment: send array with json_encode and decode your array in code before loop.

Comment: Is there any jquery / javascript function to decode the array and send it as parameter?  and if yes then how i will decode this encoded array in PHP ?

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax

Comment: For decode array in php `json_decode();` function is used :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the array to a string before passing it like so:

```
my_ary.join(',');
```

Or if it's a complex array consider JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(my_ary);
```

In case of your associative array

```
$.ajax({
   url:'url',
   data:{
      my_ary:JSON.stringify(my_ary);
   }
```

Comment: My array looks like: my_ary: Array(++++[0]+=>+Mr.+Justice+Waqar+Ahmad+Seth++++[1]+=>+Mr.+Justice+Rooh-ul-Amin+Khan+) this is the result when checked in browser developers tool

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url:'url',
  data:JSON.stringify(my_ary)
```

you need parse arrays into the string.

I hope it helps you

Comment: let suppose it work here , then how i will get values from this parameter in php page?

Comment: then you need parse JSON string into objects


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488207/convert-a-string-to-json-object-php

Answer (score 1):

Or you can format a query string like this:

```
var query_string = "action=" +  "action_name" + "&data_id=" + data_id + "&nonce=" + nonce;
```

...
data: query_string,

Answer (score -1):

Can be helpful in future for someone

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(my_ary);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'url',
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        
    });
```