# PHP json_decode returns null on valid string

Tags: php, json

I have the following code:

```
$option = $this->request->post['option'];

var_dump($option);
echo "<br>";
var_dump(json_decode($option));
```

The dumps show:

```
string(118) "{'product_option_id':276, 'product_option_value_id':132, 'name':'Цветове', 'value':'Бял', 'type':'select'}"
```

And the second one (json_decode):

```
NULL
```

Why the string can't be parsed ?

**EDIT:** 
now my json looks like this:

```
string(205) "{"product_option_id": 280, "product_option_value_id": 133, "name": "Цветове", "value": "Бежов", "type": "select"}"
```

And i added this to my code:

```
switch (json_last_error()) {
        case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            echo ' - No errors';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
            echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
            echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
            echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
            echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
        break;
        case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
            echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
        break;
        default:
            echo ' - Unknown error';
        break;
    }
```

and i returns Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single vs double quotes in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162642/single-vs-double-quotes-in-json)

Comment: Question: What character encoding scheme are you using? If anything other than UTF-8 that may be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162651/174326

If you wrap your strings in your JSON string with double quotes it'll work: 
`json_decode('{"product_option_id":276, "product_option_value_id":132, "name":"Цветове", "value":"Бял", "type":"select"}')`

Comment: I've done it the result is still the same
my first dump now looks like this: `string(196) "{"product_option_id":276, "product_option_value_id":132, "name":"Цветове", "value":"Бял", "type":"select"}" `

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are not allowed in JSON,  only double quotes. Do

```
$option = str_replace ("'", '"', $option);
```

before calling `json_decode`.

Comment: now its looks like this: `string(196) "{"product_option_id":276, "product_option_value_id":132, "name":"Цветове", "value":"Бял", "type":"select"}" `, but the result is still null

Answer (score 0):

refer [Convert a string to JSON object php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488207/convert-a-string-to-json-object-php)

you can use

```
$result = (array) json_decode($option);
```

or

```
$result = json_decode($option, true);
```

Comment: when you convert null to array you receive `array(0) {}`