# Json string conversion to json object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have been stuck in this issue and cant seem to fix it.. I have this JSON STRING

```
$unBillableArr = ["{'id' : '123','to' : '+923412268656','MsgReceivedFrom' : '03349433314', 'message':'Qwertyy ', 'recdate':'2017-11-20 19:01:49'}"];
```

I need to convert it into array of object or maybe just one json object.. I have tried doing

`json_decode($unBilledArr , true);`

It gives me null.

Already tried these solutions as well

[Convert a string to JSON object php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488207/convert-a-string-to-json-object-php)

https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/

I must be doing something wrong.. cant seem to figure out what..

P.s : This is the response i am getting and i can not do anything about the response.

Comment: That's an array containing an json string - maybe you should remove the `[]` around the "real" json-string

Comment: @Philipp yes and he should use right variable $unBillableArr  <> $unbilledArray

Comment: That's not an array of objects. That's just one json object you've put in a PHP array as a string.

Comment: I am using the right variable. that must be a typo.. @Fky

Comment: Your JSON string also uses single quotes, which `json_decode` can't work with.

Comment: i said i need to CONVERT IT INTO ARRAY OF object.. i know its a string inside an array.. This is the response i am getting and i can not do anything about the response.

Comment: So what you get is not actual JSON (wrong kinds of quotes)? Then you should really ask the supplier of this data to send standardised valid JSON; or also supply a custom decoder for PHP.

Comment: @SyedAbdurRehmanKazmi If you've got a typo in your original question, then can you please edit it? Otherwise people are just going to find issues that aren't relevant. The variable names still don't match since the last change.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning.. i have fixed that.. @iainn

Comment: @deceze this is the issue.. this is what i am getting and i have to live with this.. is there any way to get a solution out of this.

Comment: @SyedAbdurRehmanKazmi, I will amend my answer to include a solution to correct your invalid json

Comment: Since this is *not JSON*, we'd need to know what exactly it is. What is the specification for this "language"? Is the only difference to JSON that double and single quotes are… reversed? Will there ever be any sort of quotes inside those values? How will they be escaped, if at all? All these questions are already answered in JSON, which is why it's easy to work with. For this stuff here you'll have to invent your own parser, and/or haxx something together which may or may not break someday in the future when some unexpected unescaped character is being sent.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. You said that you know it's a string inside an array - why are you doing that? A JSON string inside a PHP array isn't a useful data structure, and your code still says you're trying to decode a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: @iainn 

If it was in my hand i would have def avoided it.. I am getting this response from a third party with whom i can not communicate.. This is the issue. i need a work around for it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to decode an array, either specify the specific item within the array, or make it a string.

For instance:

```
$unBillableArr = '{"id":"123", "to":"+923412268656", "MsgReceivedFrom":"03349433314", "message":"Qwertyy", "recdate":"2017-11-20 19:01:49"}';

$json = json_decode($unBillableArr, true);

// Or

$unBillableArr = ['{"id":"123", "to":"+923412268656", "MsgReceivedFrom":"03349433314", "message":"Qwertyy", "recdate":"2017-11-20 19:01:49"}'];

$json = json_decode($unBillableArr[0], true);
```

However, given the string you are receiving does not contain valid JSON and you are unable to control what you receive, I have prepared the following that will replace the single quotes in your JSON, and decode each item into an array:

```
$unBillableArr = ["{'id' : '123','to' : '+923412268656','MsgReceivedFrom' : '03349433314', 'message':'Qwertyy ', 'recdate':'2017-11-20 19:01:49'}"];

// Loop through each JSON string
$jsonObjects = []; // Change this name...
foreach ($unBillableArr as $jsonString) {
    $jsonObjects[] = json_decode(str_replace("'", '"', $jsonString), true);
}

print_r($jsonObjects); // Proof it works
```

***Please bear in mind that I would consider this to be a dirty fix. To fix this properly, you should go back to the source and ensure that the JSON they are returning to you is valid.***

Comment: This answer does not work.. i have tried this in sandbox

Comment: @SyedAbdurRehmanKazmi it does work... Trust me! Make sure you are using the correct quotes, and make sure you are referencing the correct item in the `$unBillableArr ` array

Comment: I cant change anything in this string this is the issue.. Otherwise i know it would work..

Comment: Thanks man.. @BenCarey i wanted a dirty fix. since i cant go back to main sources right now.. i told my supervisor that this is not a valid JSON and we need a proper JSON he told me to get a work around it until we are able to get in contact with them.

Comment: @SyedAbdurRehmanKazmi Find some better developers to work with :-P. Glad it sorted it, good luck!