# php curl rest api response not in json format

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

I doing a post curl request

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $headers = array();
        $headers = ["Content-Type:application/json","Accept:application/json"];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close ($ch);
        return $result;
```

The above curl request should return a json formated string but getting a string in javascript object form.

```
string(68) "{data:{errorCode:AC01,errorMessage:SansID 53563857 is exist.}}"
```

Where as when i try to do the same thing from post man api is returning perfect json.

```
{"data":{"errorCode":"AC01","errorMessage":"SansID 53563857 is exist."}}
```

Please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Whatever response you get is not the fault of the curl_* functions. Noone will be able to advise on that API without knowing more about it.

Comment: are you using var_dump() for printing response data?

Comment: i think API response is okay, please use json_decode() method for converting json to array and print that value using print_r method.

Comment: @sohanverma i used dd(), when json_decode() the string it gives NULL

Comment: okay, please use json_decode after $result = curl_exec($ch); line. please use this code: $responseArray = json_decode($result); print_r($responseArray); die;
please check my suggestion and let me know if still same error.

Comment: @sohanverma yes i did that got NULL

Comment: Please send me API name and api url?

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode to convert String into Object (stdClass) or array: 
I was having the same issue working with WordPress(cURL) and Laravel(passport) powered API that was returning JSON but in string format. I saved the response

```
//save json string into variable json object and return result
$response = curl_exec($curl);
//convert t
return (json_decode($response));
```

refer to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488207/convert-a-string-to-json-object-php.) for a similar solution

Check out this screenshot [console logs for before and after the fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwZ0n.png)